# Simple scatter plot won't work

Tags: microsoft-excel

This seems like it should be the easiest thing and I can't figure it out.

I have two columns that I want to make the X and Y axis of a scatter plot, but it refuses to use both data points. Right now I have Column A which I want to make the X axis, and Column B which I want to make the Y axis. However when I select both columns and insert Scatter Plot it uses Column B as the Y axis (great), but then the x axis just seems to correspond to the row # and it totally ignores Column A. See photo below for what comes up, I hovered over a data point so you can see it's mapped to Row 1 and then the value in column B. It's like it uses Column A as a title of the point or something but I want it to use its value.

I tried Select Data and switching Rows and Columns to see if that helps, but then it just puts both Columns A and B together somehow. I've also tried to switch the column order before creating the scatter plot and it does something equally crazy (basically puts column A on the x axis and column B on the y axis but then only maps 5 data points. WHY.). Please help, I don't know why this is so difficult and every article I read or answer I see just tells me to do exactly what I'm doing.

Using Excel 2016.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can always insert a blank scatter plot, then edit the data source and select the ranges for X and Y manually.

[image]

Second, select JUST ONE cell in the data range and insert a scatter chart. Excel will plot the first column of the range on the X axis, the second on the Y axis.

[image]

If your data is plotting as numerical categories on the X axis, check that the selected data is really numeric and not text that looks like numbers.

Finally, you may want to reduce the text in the column headings, since that will default to the series name. Keep it short and, if you need a more lengthy phrase, use the axis titles.

Comment: if that resolves your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]